Thread is not starting when calling a func
I'm working on a program to check many things periodically, and give me back data on a dashboard I made using tkinter. So, to ease the whole thread starting and Stopping threads, I created a Timer Class like so
class Timer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self._timer_runs = threading.Event()
        self._timer_runs.set()
        super().__init__()

    def start(self):
        while self._timer_runs.is_set():
            self.timed_func()
            time.sleep(self.__class__.interval)

    def stop(self):
        self._timer_runs.clear()

I then create a Subclass that will inherit from the Timer Class the start and stop function, and define timed_func() in any subclass I create later.
So... Here comes my problem.
I created my subclass, like so :
class GetDataFromPlaces(Timer):

    interval = 3600 #seconds

    def timed_func(self):
    # The code to get data from said places, tested and working correctly 

I need this function specifically to run on the start of my dashboard. Here is the code:
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timed_func = GetDataFromPlaces()
        self.timed_func.start()

The thread won't start when the Tkinter window opens. Any idea as to why?
EDIT :
I didn't mention it, but this is my first "Big project", and I'm still quite new, so appologies in advance if I don't use the correct terms, or if I said anything that's obvious, or not really usefull, or if something is missing, etc...

What is func?

It's probably the similar as this article. What is the notation for a callable instance parameter?

@MichaelButscher Updated to make it clearer. Is it better ?

A bit. What is self.timer in class Timer?

Please extract a [mcve] to illustrate the problem.

Did you mean to override run instead of start?

Side note, "Timer" isn't a good name for this class. threading already has a Timer object whose job is to run code after some time period has passed. This code could be "BackgroundTask" or something like that.

The question is too broad imo. The thread won't start because you've never called the super().start(...), a method of the base Thread class, but that's not the actual problem you're solving. You're basically asking how to implement an idea you have based on your sketch that needs (lots of) improvement and/or rewriting. This is absolutely fine, you're new to this, but don't bite off more than you can chew. Take one step at a time: first, figure out how Thread objects work and how they are usually used. Start with a toy example on plain functions instead of unnecessary subclassing.

You say the thread didn't start, but it looks like the thread code ran in the calling thread, blocking future code from running.

Thread.start is the method that starts the thread. By overriding it, you skip creating the thread and instead run the code in the calling thread. The solution is simple - override the run method instead.
class Timer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self._timer_runs = threading.Event()
        self._timer_runs.set()
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while self._timer_runs.is_set():
            self.timed_func()
            time.sleep(self.__class__.interval)

    def stop(self):
        self._timer_runs.clear()

When you call the base Thread.start method, it will create a thread and run the run method. That's just the base functionality of the class.

Thank you very much for that. It does indeed start when I change run instead of start.. But as you said above, I'll prpbably try to play arround with threading much more before implementing it.
